# JQuery fadeOut callback function is being executed after fadeOut is over

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

On a click of a button, i'm trying to fadeOut an image, and while it is fading out i'm changing the source of the image.  And then i'm using the fadeIn to show the new image.  This works fine in Chrome, and firefox.  However, in ie10, the image fades out, fades in, and then the new image appears.  I can't find a a fix for it.  I've tried to prolong the duration of fadeOut, fadeIn.  I've tried using setTimeout function.  i've tried using promise().done() function.  I've tried using Jquery UI's hide/show w/ slide effect, and same issues are appearing.  Nothing seems to be working.  I'd really appreciate any help.  Thanks

```
me.$el.find('#printable-detail-static-imageRight').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                            me.$el.find('#printable-detail-static-imageRight').attr('src', me.options.samplePrints[k+i]);
                            me.disableNext();
                        });

                        me.$el.find('#printable-detail-static-imageRight').fadeIn('slow')
```

Comment: is this because the image isn't loaded? try having the an img tag in your page showing the second image, just to test it..

Comment: also you don't need `me.$el.find('#printable-detail-static-imageRight')` within the fade out function. use `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to put the `.fadeIn` method inside the callback function in order for it to be affected by the callback function. In fact, I'd add another callback function to the `.attr` method to make sure that it fades back in only after the `src` has been changed.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/eanAc/) a jsFiddle I wrote to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: @Turtleweezard...this code works on other browsers but on ie.  ie still fades out, fades in and then image is getting changed.  while on chrome and firefox, it works perfectly.

Comment: Dang. I really wish I knew enough about jQuery to fix that... "Darn you Internet Explorer!!!"

Answer (score 1):

i am on a mac, but does this code works in ie ? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/b36Jp/)

.html

```
<div id="content">Promises</div>
<button id="click">start animation</button>
```

.js

```
$("#click").on("click", function () {
    $('#content').fadeOut({
        duration: 1000,
        // run when the animation is complete
        complete: function () {
            $("#content").append($("<div>").addClass("fakeimg"));
        },
        // run when the animation is complete + 
        //it's promise is resolved
        done: function () {
            $('#content').fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But will it work when you're attempting to change the src attribute of an image?

Comment: In that case I approve of this solution. +1

Comment: It fades out, fades in, but the picture doesn't change.

Comment: @rusln  This code is working in ie, but it's giving me the same issues as before.  In ie, the current picture fades out, it fades back in with the current picture for fractions of a second, and then the image changes

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
 me.$el.find('#printable-detail-static-imageRight').animate({
                        opacity:0
                    }, {
                        duration: 700,
                        step: function(now, fx){
                            if(fx.pos > 0.40 && fx.pos < 0.5){
                                $(this).attr('src', me.options.samplePrints[k+i]);
                                me.disableNext();
                            }
                            if (fx.pos ==1) {
                                $(this).animate({
                                    opacity:1
                                }, 200);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```